# SublimeClang C++11 auto complete with type inference

Tags: c++, c++11, sublimetext2, clang

I'm using SublimeClang with C++11, but can't get auto completion working on variables defined as auto.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void foo();
}

...

auto mine = new MyClass;
mine-> // Would like auto completion here
```

Do I have to do something special in order to get it working or is this feature not implemented?

My sublimeclang settings file:

```
"additional_language_options":
{
     "c++" : ["-std=c++11"],
     "c": [],
     "objc": [],
     "objc++": []
}
```

Comment: that project is dead, use this https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe with vim